# Extended Splashscreen on Windows 8 App for Login in C# (MySql)

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, xaml, windows-8

I'm looking at embarking on my first Windows 8 store app. I've just created a MySql DB called 'secure_login' and within this DB I have a table called 'members' with the fields:-

```
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY 
  `username` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
  `email` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
  `password` CHAR(40) NOT NULL
```

The password field will be a SHA-1 calculation.

What I am looking to do is when the app is initiated by the user, I want the app to present an extended splashscreen which will present the login screen for the user to enter their username and password. I'd then be looking to put a function in C# in the app to calculate the SHA-1 of the password entered and then pass the username and password SHA-1 value to the DB to compare. If correct, the user can then move onto the app however if it's incorrect they are presented with the option to reattempt to login or exit.

I also have a table to monitor user login-attempts which is as below:

```
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `time` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
```

For each attempt (successful or unsuccesful), I'd like this to also be logged. My DB doesn't reflect it as yet but I'd somehow like to record if indeed the login was successful but unsure how to capture this at the DB end.

I'm not that new to C# but I'm new to the world of XAML and connecting to DBs for user authentication.

Any suggestions on the above or recommendations? I've found a few guides to using the Windows Live logins but not using unique ones.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the ms [guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh965453.aspx) for login controls, if they solve your problem great :D

Personally I like to have an indirection when having login on apps. The apps have a single start page so instead of showing content after it is loaded the page decides if it should login or should go the content.

Simply imagine that your app start page is `StartView.xaml`, this one checks if the user is logged in, if so the app navigate to `HomeView.xaml`, if not the app navigates to `LoginView.xaml`